# Open any file from within a java program

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser

Opening files in java seems a bit tricky -- for .txt files one must use a File object in conjunction with a Scanner or BufferedReader object -- for image IO, one must use an ImageIcon class -- and if one is to literally open a .txt document (akin to double-clicking the application) from java, this code seems to work:

```
import java.io.*;

public class LiterallyOpenFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("notepad Text.txt");
    }
}
```

I'm not positive, but I think other file-types / names can be substituted in the parenthesis after exec -- anyway, I plan on opening certain files in a JFileChooser when the user clicks on a file to open (when the user clicks on a file, the path to the file can be obtained with the getSelectedFile() method).  Though I'm more specifically looking to be able to open an Arduino file in the Arduino IDE from a java program, like a simulated double-click.. perhaps something like this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class LiterallyOpenFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("Arduino C:\\Arduino\\fibonacci_light\\fibonacci_light.ino");
    }
}
```

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: On Windows, you can always use `start` to open any file using its default file assocation. So instead of `notepad` or `arduino` or what not, replace all of them with `start`.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this? If there is a registered program for your file in windows, this should work. (i.e. the default application should open the file)

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(file);
```

The file parameter is a `File` object.

[Link to API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

[Link to use cases and implementation example of the Desktop class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: @Woodrow I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic on this answer, but as far as I understand your question, this is the correct answer. read up the documentation of the Desktop class:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Comment: @Christian R.   Wasn't sarcasm, just something odd involving arduino files:  http://imgur.com/xQaYvy5   meaning the arduino file itself has to be located inside of a folder inside the desktop -- so I can use the Desktop class to open the folder that contains the file, but not the file directly.  & thanks, I plan on reading up on the Desktop class.

Comment: you mix up the folder "Desktop" (what it is called in windows and other OS') with the class name, but for your challenge it fits perfectly - the file does not have to be inside the Desktop folder - the parameter could be any file object that is: not null, the file exists, is readable by security constraints and there is a associated application that could be launched with the file - if you take the file object from your `JFileChooser.getSelected()` as parameter, the file itself should be opened with the associated application

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in my projects using `java.awt.Desktop`

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;    
public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
              Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\Hamza\\Desktop\\image.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```